# Changing material ui IconButton hovered style doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make the custom hovered style of `IconButton` and I am doing it as

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&:hover": {
      borderRadius: "4px",
      padding: "3px",
    },
  },
}));

return (
  <div className="App">
    <IconButton aria-label="previous" className={classes.root}>
      <ArrowLeftIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </div>
);
```

But when I hover it, it's flickering and not changing smoothly. I think I am missing some styles to add, but I can't find a way what I'm doing wrong. You can see my codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-heisenberg-cbskf?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [default styles for IconButton](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.js#L17), you'll find that the `borderRadius` and `padding` are set directly in the root styles. Only the `backgroundColor` changes on hover.

If you make the corresponding change to your styles, then it works fine:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderRadius: "4px",
    padding: "3px"
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit IconButton borderRadius]

Answer (score 0):

It's flickering on hover because the `padding` (the space between its content and border) is modified. Either remove the `padding` or put it in the default style.

> not changing smoothly

This can be easily solved by using css transition. Material-UI [`theme`](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme) has a utility method `theme.transition.create()` to help you create transition quickly.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["border-radius"]),
    // padding: 3;

    "&:hover": {
      borderRadius: "4px"
    }
  }
}));
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit jovial-snow-53eno]